# Артефакты изображений при изменении размера на PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick

На сайте сначала был скрипт на основе GD. С помощью него менялся размер у внешней фотографии (например указывал просто http://site.ru/foto.jpg) и сохранялся на моем сервере.

Скрипт работал нормально, но иногда почему то изображение сохранялось с артефактами, прикладываю пример.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем если удалить созданное фото на сервер и заново запустить скрипт, фото сохраниться без артефактов. То есть происходит такое совершенно без зависимости от времени и источника фото.

Думал проблема в библиотеке GD, но решил поменять скрипт на основе ImageMagick и проблема все равно осталась.

Сейчас скрипт выглядит таким образом:

```
$file = 'http://site.ru/foto.jpg';   
$image = new Imagick($file);
$image->cropThumbnailImage(549, 366);
$image->setImageFormat( 'jpeg' );
$image->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG); 
$image->setImageCompressionQuality(87);
$url_name_gal = '/var/www/images/'.$r['id'].'.jpg';
$image->writeImage($url_name_gal);
```

Некоторые фото вообще отказывается изменять, например из этого источника: https://pronedra.ru/upkeep/uploads/2019/07/Turtsiya-400x300.jpg

В чем может быть проблема? Не поможет ли сначала загружать все фото на свой сервер и потом изменять их?

Comment: В какой-то момент заголовок jpg изображения ломается, прочтите метаданные изображения - может специально что-то туда записали или просто не корректны

Comment: @Ghost, Я не пробовал на других серверах, а по поводу не корректного фото, я же писал, что если его удалить и заново запустить скрипт, то все будет ок

Comment: Лучше всего скачать а потом манипуляции проводить

Comment: @Ghost, почему то даже https://pronedra.ru/upkeep/uploads/2019/07/Turtsiya-400x300.jpg не скачивается. Скачиваю так: 'file_put_contents('/var/www/images/', file_get_contents('https://pronedra.ru/upkeep/uploads/2019/07/Turtsiya-400x300.jpg'));'